# "GLib-ERROR **: Cannot create pipe main loop wake-up: Too many open files" on Qt

Tags: qt, crash, gdb

I am working on Ubuntu. When I run my program about after 1 hour I received this error :

**GLib-ERROR **: Cannot create pipe main loop wake-up: Too many open files                       The program has unexpectedly finished.**

When I run with gdb it does not crash.

I Don't understand why? and What is the reason for this error ?

Thank you very much..

Comment: Solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038133/python-qt-qnetworkrequest-exits-with-process3265-glib-error-creating-pi

Answer (score 2):

> Too many open files

Is pretty obvious. Probalby you have a leak with file descriptors, so you should check if your code opens lots of files/filedescriptors but doesn't close them properly. If you fork a process, you should also consider to close them, before you start the actual process, as this might also be a common mistake.

The operating system has a limited table of how many filedescreptors it can maintain, and apparently you exceeded this limit.

Comment: I use QAccessNetworkManager in my project. what is '**File Descriptor**' here ??

Comment: The error comes from the operating system and even iof the files are hidden somewhere in the classes, you must still make sure that they are properly closed. Since you don't give any example code, it's hard to say what you are doing wrong.

Comment: On linux, everything is a file. You can take a look what open files are used: ``lsof``. Probably will give you a very long list. You can filter this by: ``lsof -i`` for socket connections, ``lsof -f`` for real filestreams, ...

Comment: Soryy I understand you now.. what can I do? Or there are how a mistake in my project? Because I analyzed with Valgrind. there are definitely lost about 30 MB.. Does it have any relevance  ?

Comment: 30MB sounds like a start. :) I'm pretty asure that the classes have appropriate code to close files, if they are keeping some, but if you don't delete them this is not going to happen. So I would go with what valgrind tells you.