# GLib-ERROR **: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files qt on Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, runtime-error

I built a program that save coordinates and images into SQLite every 1 second, I use QT 5 for the project, the program run normally for small iterations but when the program certain iterations (e.g 3000+ iteration) it cause an error

> GLib-ERROR **: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files qt on Qt5

note: the images is taken from camera that connected with ethernet cable to the computer, the computer I used is single board computer odroid c2

here is the [code](https://github.com/kikirizki/satellitemodem/blob/master/dbmodule.cpp)

Comment: Not much anyone can do for you without more information, but "Too many open files" has me thinking you should go looking for anywhere you might be opening and not closing a socket, file, or pipe.

Comment: I have edit the question and I add the code https://github.com/kikirizki/satellitemodem/blob/master/dbmodule.cpp

Comment: thank you for your comment i will check out my code may be there is some open file that i forget to close

Comment: this advice to check for open file descriptors helped me to trace the source of this problem in my case - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17969854/692829